# Accessing values from a map with pairs

Tags: c++, dictionary

This is the decleration and initialization of map :

```
    static std::map<VehicleType, std::pair<int const, int const>> TypeToFee = {
            {MOTORBIKE, make_pair(FIRST_HOUR_FEE_MOTOR, HOURLY_FEE_MOTOR)},
            {CAR, make_pair(FIRST_HOUR_FEE_CAR, HOURLY_FEE_CAR)},
            {HANDICAPPED, make_pair(HANDICAPPED_FEE, HANDICAPPED_FEE)}
    };
    static std::map<VehicleType, std::pair<int const, int const>> ::iterator map_iter;
```

What is the python equivalent of (assume I get `type` variable as a parameter which contains either `CAR, MOTORBIKE, HANDICAPPED`)

```
TypeToFee[type]
```

And how do I get only the first or second value from each pair ?

I looked up and found `find` function but I dont fully understand on how to implement this on my example.

Comment: Is this a C++ question or a Python question?

Comment: Are you trying to construct a view on `TypeToFee`? A view that maps `VehicleType` to only the first element of each value in `TypeToFee` and another on the second elements?

Comment: Trying to do line-by-line translations from C++ to some other language (or some other language to C++) is not the way to go about doing this.  You need to understand, on a high-level, *what* the code is attempting to accomplish.

Comment: @Steve its a c++ question.
I just gave the python syntax to what I need in case that clarifies the question for someone

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. It works with the same syntax as in Python (though the semantics for when a key isn't found are different). I suggest you provide a [repro] of your approach that failed and the reason it failed (e.g. error messages). And the elements of a pair are accessed the same way they always are: ẁith `.first` and `.second`.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `std::pair`? That's what `TypeToFee[type]` returns.

Comment: So ```TypeToFee[CAR].first = FIRST_HOUR_FEE_CAR``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [C++17 structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
VehicleType type = /* ... */;
auto const [ lhs, rhs ] = TypeToFee[type];
```

With C++11, or if you wish to completely discard `lhs` or `rhs` you can use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) with [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore):

```
VehicleType type = /* ... */;
int const rhs;
std::tie(std::ignore, rhs) = TypeToFee[type];
```

or better yet,

```
VehicleType type = /* ... */;
auto const rhs = TypeToFee[type].second;
```

Comment: I'm compiling with c++11 .. don't have the freedom to change the version.